# Root directory duplicated in /media/media on Ubuntu Linux server

Tags: linux, rsync

Something weird happened while running an rsync command.

I first mounted a Windows share to copy files to like this:

**mount -t cifs //myserver/share] /media/s**

Then ran rsync command below

**sudo rsync -avprP /* /media/s/Backup --exclude '/backups' '/media'**

Now that I look at it, did the above rsync command not exclude /media, but actually back up to it?  Guessing I put the --exclude in wrong order or syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `--exclude` only takes a single argument. Try `--exclude '/backups' --exclude '/media'`. (Actually, you don't need the single quotes around either of those, but they don't hurt.)

Comment: Thank you!  So would the above command explain why my entire server was copied to /media/media?  I want to make sure before I delete the contents of /media/media/* :)  Thanks!

Comment: The existing command will copy everything under `/` except `/backups`, plus an extra copy of `/media/s/Backup` in addition, into bare `/media`. Thus, `/media/media` will contain a duplicate of everything that was previously under `/media`. You can probably delete all that, though you should make sure it's actually superfluous as a sanity check.